# What version of R should I use for installing SingleCellExperiment package using conda?

Tags: r, anaconda, conda, r-package

I am pretty new in coding with R and installing packages in conda. I want to install *SingleCellExperiment* package in my conda environment in which I have installed R version 4.1.3. I tried to run:

```
conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-singlecellexperiment
```

however, it throws a lot of dependencies errors. I looked into bioconductor page in [SingleCellExperiment](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/SingleCellExperiment.html) and above the code I see it is mentioned R version 4.3 and in dependencies I see *SummarizedExperiment* is mentioned. I have two questions:

1. Does 4.3 mean that I should look into lower versions of this package for R 4.1?
2. Should I try to install SummarizedExperiment beforehand? and then install my package? or as it is conda released package, I should expect everything is maintained and installed by running the above command?

Comment: Best recommendation is to update to the most recent version of R.

Comment: Just a general note regarding `conda` -  try to create a new environment while including all your package requirements in one go.  Maybe it's better now, but going with a fresh env instead of updating and adding packages to an existing one used to be a less stressful experience. I'd also prefer miniconda (or miniforge / mambaforge distribution) over full conda distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Bioconductor pins its releases to R versions, so choosing to use R 4.1 means all your Bioconductor software will be nearly 2 years old. There's nothing necessarily wrong with older versions (papers I submit today used them), but when visiting documentation it will be about latest versions, and the single-cell tools are constantly rolling out new features. So, I'd recommend always starting a new environment for each analysis project and grab the latest versions.

It's also a good habit to use YAML or lockfiles to define environments, rather than *ad hoc* install commands (e.g., `conda install`). E.g.,

**sce_bioc_3_17.yaml**

```yaml
name: sce_bioc_3_17
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - nodefaults  # exclude all other channels
dependencies:
  ## R and CRAN packages
  - r-base=4.3
  - r-magrittr
  - r-tidyverse

  ## Bioconductor packages
  - bioconductor-biocgenerics=0.46  # this effectively sets Bioc 3.17
  - bioconductor-singlecellexperiment
  - bioconductor-tidysinglecellexperiment
  # ... include every package you expect to need
```

Create with

```bash
conda env create -n sce_bioc_3_17 -f sce_bioc_3_17.yaml
```